# Pass a Python list to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json, flask

I'm having some issues passing a Python list to JavaScript as an array. My code is below, and outputs a blank screen, with error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined'.

### main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_view():
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    jsarray = json.dumps(array)
    return render_template('index.html', array=jsarray)

app.run()
```

### index.html

```
<script>
    var data = JSON.parse(array)
    document.write(data)
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean `JSON.parse({{ array }})`?

Comment: @jarmod just tried that change, still get the same error in the console and also getting error in the script: 'Property assignment expected'

Comment: Ah, presumably being injected as text so needs quotes: `JSON.parse("{{ array }}")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jinja2 filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson). A conversion of the data to JSON within the route is not necessary. You can simply pass the list to the template.

```
@app.route('/')
def my_view():
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return render_template('index.html', array=array)
```

```
<script>
   const data = {{ array | tojson }};
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your index.html to

## index.html

```js
<script>
    var data = JSON.parse({{ array }})
    document.write(data)
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error in the console, as well as new errors in the script (https://imgur.com/a/EK4j7LK)